# Extending typing with a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a js SDK with some plugin.

I'm working on the typing of it.

My code is something like this:

```
import Sdk from "./sdk";
import ProductsPlugin from "./sdk/plugins/products";
import UsersPlugin from "./sdk/plugins/users";

const sdk = new Sdk({
  apiBaseUrl: "http://www.foo.bar"
});

sdk.usePlugin(ProductsPlugin)
sdk.usePlugin(UsersPlugin)
```

In this moment I would like to extend sdk with methods added by the plugins like:

```
sdk.ProductsPlugin.addProcut(....)
```

the idea is to have a small SDK which can be extend with the plugins the client need.

How can I extend the typing so when I have `sdk.ProductsPlugin.` I get the autocomplete suggesting the added methods

The code so far is something like this:

```
class Sdk {
  usePlugin(PluginClass) {
    new PluginClass(this);
  }
}


class Plugin {
    sdk: Sdk;

    constructor(sdk: Sdk) {
        this.sdk = sdk;
        const pluginName = this.constructor.name.replace("Plugin", "");
        sdk[pluginName] = this;
    }
}

class FirstPlugin extends Plugin {

    boo(){
        alert(1)
    }
}


const instance = new Sdk()


instance.usePlugin(FirstPlugin)


instance.First.boo();
```

The issue is that i do not have autocomplete for `.First`

Comment: You would use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

Comment: Although you will find it hard to have TypeScript understand that `sdk.usePlugin(Foo)` will suddently cause `sdk.Foo` to exist.  That's not how the type system works; calling a method on an object does not change the type of the object.  Instead you'd have to do something like have `sdk.usePlugin(Foo)` return another `Sdk` object known to contain a `Foo` and you use that one afterward.

Comment: Could you edit the code here to constitute a [mcve]?  There's just too many possibilities for how `Sdk`, `ProductsPlugin`, and `UsersPlugin` might act for me to give a targeted useful answer.  Ideally you'd give some code you could just drop into a standalone IDE or a web IDE like [repl.it](https://repl.it/).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to do what you want you might need to relax a few of your implicit requirements.

First, there's no statightforward way for the compiler to understand that `sdk.usePlugin()` will change the *type* of `sdk` so as to have more properties.  The closest you're going to get is to have `sdk.usePlugin()` return `this` of a changed type, and use method chaining (as in a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)) when configuring an `Sdk`.

Second, if you want the compiler to statically know what the name of the plugin under `Sdk` will be, you need to provide it as a [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) type that is part of your `Plugin` type definition.  Perhaps `Plugin` should even be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) class that depends on this name, (and abstract if it needs to be subclassed to be useful)

Here's how you might go about it:

```
class Sdk {
    usePlugin<P extends Plugin<any>>(PluginClass: new (sdk: Sdk) => P) {
        new PluginClass(this);
        return this as this & Record<ReturnType<P["getPluginName"]>, P>;
    }
}

abstract class Plugin<Name extends string> {
    sdk: Sdk & Record<Name, this>;
    abstract getPluginName(): Name; // have to let the compiler know what name to use

    constructor(sdk: Sdk) {
        this.sdk = sdk as any; // hard to convince compiler this is okay
        this.sdk[this.getPluginName()] = this as any; // hard to convince the compiler this is okay
    }
}

class FirstPlugin extends Plugin<"First"> {
    getPluginName() {
        return "First" as "First"; // or as const in TS3.4+
    }

    boo() {
        alert(1);
    }
}

const instance = new Sdk();

// have to assign to new var
const instanceWithFirst = instance.usePlugin(FirstPlugin);

instanceWithFirst.First.boo();
```

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#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-eYd9PF6vFckPl3z5ZtW37aYgA)

I hope that gives you some direction.  Good luck!

Comment: Amazing! You did it!
Is what I was looking for.